# using jQuery, how can I resize child elements on load and resize

Tags: jquery

I have a pretty basic function:

```
 function bx_thumbs() {
    pager_count = jQuery('.bx-pager').children().size();
    total_width = jQuery('.bx-pager').width();
    item_width_margin = pager_count*16;
    page_width = total_width-item_width_margin;
    item_width = page_width/pager_count;

    jQuery('.bx-pager a img').each(function(){
        jQuery(this).css('width',item_width+'px')
        console.log('hi' + total_width);        
    });  
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  bx_thumbs();
});
jQuery(window).resize(function() {
  bx_thumbs();
 });
```

The goal of this is to set the images to a width that keeps things all on one row.

this works just fine on load. but on resize while I get the console log, the images loose their width setting.

You can see this in action at http://simpleandcrisp.com/pairings

I have css max-width set in my css so that it doesn't blow up the page if js is deactivated... Just can't figure out why it doesnt work on resize.

thanks in advance

Comment: I know it may sound like it's unrelated but it's really not I promise... Have you looked into the Twitter Bootstrap?
They have some really good css classes mixed with CSS Media Queries that pretty much takes care of this for you.

Comment: I use it in other projects but this one we didn't

Comment: Did you test the resize function with an alert?

Comment: Try this:

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery(window).resize(function() {
        bx_thumbs();
      }).trigger('resize');// triggers initial resize
    });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noted by SegioCruz above:

Try this: jQuery(document).ready(function() { jQuery(window).resize(function() { bx_thumbs(); }).trigger('resize');// triggers initial resize });